# How to have any popup in firefox open as a tab instead

Tags: firefox, popups

I used to have a custom about:config setting that made it so that any popup a page would generate was opened in a new tab instead.

With my new install, I can't remember the name of this setting. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction` set to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you the name of the setting, but you mention having a "new install."  If you are trying to configure firefox on a new machine, or if you think you will have to do this in the future, I highly recommend this [little java applet](http://code.google.com/p/portprofile/).  It is an absolute gem.  Forget importing bookmarks and any reconfiguration.  This program will take your entire firefox profile and convert to a format which it will later use to *import* to your new machine.

Hope it's at least a little help for the future if not right now! ;)

Comment: That is cool, but isn't really an answer.

Comment: Nifty little thing. I'll be sure to use it.